# munin monitoring cpu usage - add new group

Tags: linux, debian, munin

The graph under `System > CPU usage`

Is it possible to add new groups/curves? I would like to see how much CPU both PHP and Mysql consume each

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the [cpubyprocess plugin](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/blob/master/plugins/cpu/cpu-usage-by-process).

Usage:

```
# Plugin to monitor CPU usage, for a selected set of processes. Tested on FreeBSD.
#
# Author: Erik Cederstrand
# Based on http://waste.mandragor.org/munin_tutorial/cpubyuser
# Thanks to Yann Hamon.
#
# Usage: Place in /usr/local/etc/munin/plugins/ (or link it there  using ln -s)
#        Add this to your /ur/local/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/plugins.conf:
#       [cpubyproc]
#       env.procs httpd java
```